# gnuplot one graph with two axes (dB and intensity)

Tags: gnuplot

I need to plot one graph representing a sound in function of a duration. The sound needs to be scaled by intensity (power) and dB.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
gnuplot <<EOF

# first part duration this is easy
set terminal png size 1024,768 enhanced font "Helvetica,20"
set output 'output.png'
set yrange [0:60];
set ylabel "duration";
set ytics 5 nomirror textcolor lt 1;

# second part intensity and dB
set xrange [0:100];
set xlabel "intensity";
set xtics 5 nomirror textcolor lt 1;
set x2range [0:10];
set x2label "dB";
set x2tics 5 nomirror textcolor lt 1;
plot \
"data.dat" using 2:1 axes x1y1 title 'Graph' with points pt 7 ps 4,\
"data.dat" using 2:1 linetype 1 axes x2y1 title '';
```

The trouble is if the two axes originates and terminates correctly, the dispersion of values for the dB (log(intensity/intensity_ref)) is not the same as those of intensity, perfectly proportional.

How can I specify a formula for one axe? Not only for sound graphics, is it possible to specify a formula for dispersion around one axe? (I would also like if I can have two x axes with, say, x and x^2 dispersion).

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To plot the intensity in linear scale on one axis and in dB on the other axis you must apply an appropriate scaling on the respective columns:

```
plot 'data.dat' using 2:1, 'data.dat' using (log10(column(2))):1 axes x2y1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need to do, however, from bash script, $2 is not recognized as column, but instead returns: `(log10(/intensity_ref)):1`.
It does not return anything (and does not plot neither) when I execute the script with gnuplot directly. Thanks for replying anyway

Comment: Ups, missed that. Use `column(2)`.